# Eigenfunctions for the symmetric kernel of an integral equation

Tags: integral-equations, orthonormal, eigenfunctions

The solution of the symmetric integral equation below:
$$g(s) = f(s) + \lambda \int_{-1}^{1} (st +s^2t^2)g(t)dt \tag{$*$}$$
with *separable kernels method* is
$$g(s) = f(s) + \lambda \int_{-1}^{1} (\frac{st}{(1-\frac{2}{3}\lambda)}+\frac{s^2t^2}{(1-\frac{2}{5}\lambda)} )f(t) dt$$
let $f(s)=(s+1)^2$ and $\lambda = 1$ in $(*)$, i.e let:
$$g(s) = (s+1)^2 + \int_{-1}^{1} (st +s^2t^2)g(t)dt \tag{$**$}$$
The question is, How I can (maybe using of the Hilbert-Schmidt theorem to) find the *eigenfunctions* corresponding to eigenvalues $\lambda_1 = \frac{3}{2}, \lambda_2 = \frac{5}{2}$ for the symmetric kernel in $(**)$?

> The issue in the question has also *briefly* been surveyed in the first example appeared on the 153th page of the book titled "**Linear Integral Equations**" by *Ram P. Kanwal*.
>
> The picture blow is an extraction from the second edition of aforementioned reference.
> [image]

Answer (score 1):

Late answer, still, for the sake of those who might land here looking for detailed explanation here:

You can solve for resolvent kernel as in Example 4 in Section 2.2 of Ram P Kanwal, to get
$$\Gamma(s,t;\lambda)=\frac{st}{1-\frac23\lambda}+\frac{s^2t^2}{1-\frac25\lambda}$$

Putting $\lambda=1$ as in question, we get 
$$\Gamma(s,t;\lambda)=\frac{st}{1-\frac23}+\frac{s^2t^2}{1-\frac25}$$

Taking $\dfrac32$ common in the first term, and $\dfrac25$ common in second term, we get
$$\Gamma(s,t;\lambda)=\frac{st}{\frac23(\frac32-\lambda)}+\frac{s^2t^2}{\frac25(\frac52-\lambda)}=\frac{\frac32st}{\frac32-\lambda}+\frac{\frac52s^2t^2}{\frac52-\lambda}\tag{1}$$

By preceding theory, we have
$$\Gamma(s,t;\lambda)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty{\phi_k(s)\phi^*_k(t)\over\lambda_k-\lambda}$$
where

1. $\lambda=1$
2. $\lambda_1=\dfrac32$
3. $\lambda_2=\dfrac52$ and
4. $\phi^*_k=\phi_k$ since integral is over real numbers.

Hence
$$\Gamma(s,t;\lambda)=\frac{\phi_1(s)\phi_1(t)}{\frac32-1}+\frac{\phi_2(s)\phi_2(t)}{\frac52-1}\tag{2}$$

Comparing equations (1) and (2),
$$\phi_1(s)=\sqrt\frac32s,\ \phi_2(s)=\sqrt\frac52s^2$$

Where multiplying with $\dfrac{\sqrt2}{\sqrt2}$ in denominator and numerator gives the desired result.

(Note: there is a mistake in print; $\phi_2(s)=\sqrt{\dfrac52}s^2$, and not $\phi_2(s)=\sqrt{\dfrac{10}2}s^2$ - corrected in the very next step in textbook.)

Answer (score 0):

If you solve the eigenvalue problem $g(s) = \lambda \int_{-1}^{1} (st +s^2t^2)g(t)dt $, you will find the two eigenvalues $\lambda_1=3/2$ and $\lambda_2=5/2$, and their corresponding eigenfunctions. The coefficients of the eigenfunctions are determined by the normalization condition $\int_{-1}^1 \phi(x)^2 dx=1$.

Comment: A little late question, can you please elaborate?